# C# displaying an image according to the selection

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, image

there are two images in my page for those am using only one imagebutton and showing as per the startup functionality.

Now i want to have a clickable link one image and for other it should not be clickable.

Example

```
 if(userselection == chocolate)
 userselimg.imageurl="~/chocolate.jpg"
 if(userselection == coffee)
 userselimg.imageurl="~/coffee.jpg"
```

and i want add a link [this is not a link](http://example.com) to 2nd option i.e coffee and no link  for chocolate.
Here i am one imagebutton for both conditions.

kindly advice me

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Show your work first.. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: Try making fiddle for your problem sample

Answer (score 0):

Click on first image and go to link:

```
$("#img1").click(function(){
     var url = 'https://www.google.co.in/';
     $(location).attr('href', url);
});
```

To unbind the click of second image use [**unbind**](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Comment: here i am using only one imagebutton and showing image like below
     if(userselection == chocolate)
     userselimg.imageurl="~/chocolate.jpg"
     if(userselection == coffee)
     userselimg.imageurl="~/coffee.jpg"

Comment: u need to ask qus in proper way ..ur needs changes after half an hour